# Access folder right-click from inside the folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, context-menu

In Windows XP, if you had a folder open in Explorer, you could access the right-click context menu of a folder by right-clicking the folder icon in the titlebar of the Explorer window.  In Win7 this no longer works.  Right-clicking the background of the open folder, or right-clicking the folder icon in the info pane at the bottom, does not give the same context menu; there are items that are not in these menus, but are in the menu when I right-click on a folder from outside it.

Given that I have a folder open in Explorer, how can I, without navigating out of the folder, access the same right-click context menu that I would get if I navigated to the parent folder and right-clicked my target folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can show the folder pane in the left side of the explorer windows and right-click on that one. To automatically show the folder that you have opened on the left side, go to "tools"-"folder options" and check the lowest box on the first panel.

I do not think there is a way to replicate the Windows XP behavior 1:1.